# Best method for submitting disabled form fields in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, post, submit

There seem to be several ways to submit (POST) disabled form fields in jQuery:

- Have a hidden field that changes when the input changes, and submit that
- Manually append the key/value pairs upon submission
- Revert values on the server-side (only if values not expected to change)

I was wondering which (if any) is considered best practice for submitting disabled form fields.  Obviously `readOnly` is the best option when it's available, but I have checkboxes that I need to submit even though they are disabled (due to business logic).  I realize this is not an ideal situation, but rarely is that the case in web development.

Is there a best-practice for submitting disabled form elements?

Comment: The disabled form elements shouldn't be submitted. The correct way to do that, is creating hidden inputs on submit. Here's the HTML documentation: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#successful-controls

Comment: @Dave So you're saying option 1 is the best choice?  That's what I was leaning towards, too.  Also, thanks for the documentation.

Comment: @GrailsGuy With regards to your first option, if you have a disabled form field, why would the input ever change?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best option is to make the inputs readonly - create a click event for the check boxes that simply returns false, and change their background color.

There is no best practice, but that one requires the least fudging.

Answer (score 5):

A fourth solution would be to enable the check boxes before submitting the form:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $("input:checkbox", this).prop("disabled", false);
});
```

You can use a more sophisticated selector if you do not want to re-enable all the check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way if require to post all or certain disbaled inputs:

1. Step1: give a class name name (eg. mod).
2. Step2: onSubmit, enabled all the those fields following the example below:

   $("input[class=mod]").removeAttr('disabled');
3. Step3: Post data
4. Step4: Disable those fields again (if required) following the example below:

   $("input[class=mod]").attr('disabled="disabled"');